# string concatenation in loop

Tags: java, string, concatenation

Good evening all,

Probably a simple fix but I just cannot find it.
I made this to print out every second chr from a string:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string:");

    String input = sc.next();
    String total = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 2){
        total += input.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

It works like a charm, but the '+=' is highlighted and gives me the tip: string concatenation in loop. Am I using a wrong method to accomplish what I want?

Comment: You should use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Yes, string concat is a costly operation (in terms of performance) due to immutability of string. You should be using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: normally these types of hints are accompanied by alternatives or even refactoring options, are you sure you cannot simply do that? Or are you asking out of curiousity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i += 2){
    total.append(input.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(total.toString());
```

See also:

http://www.pellegrino.link/2015/08/22/string-concatenation-with-java-8.html

Comment: `new StringBuilder((input.length()+1)/2)`, if you want to be more efficient (it preallocates the internal array, so it doesn't have to be resized).

Comment: could you please add explanation *why* it's more efficient? I suppose then answer be more helpful

Comment: Or, just print the chars directly to `System.out`.

Comment: @ADS The provided link explains this in full.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!